# Shift values in pandas dataframe vertically by one row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], 
     'user': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
     'date': ['2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-02', '2010-03-03', '2010-03-03', '2010-03-03']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

value   user    date
1       A       2010-03-02
2       A       2010-03-02
3       A       2010-03-02
4       A       2010-03-02
5       A       2010-03-02
6       A       2010-03-02
7       A       2010-03-02
8       A       2010-03-02
9       B       2010-03-02
10      B       2010-03-02
11      B       2010-03-02
12      B       2010-03-02
13      C       2010-03-02
14      C       2010-03-02
15      C       2010-03-02
16      C       2010-03-02
17      C       2010-03-02
18      C       2010-03-02
19      C       2010-03-02
20      C       2010-03-02
21      A       2010-03-03 
22      A       2010-03-03
23      A       2010-03-03
```

I would like to create a new column called `value2` to this dataframe, populate it with the same values from the `value` column, but with the rows shifted upwards by one row. The last row of each `user` and `date` group group should be removed too. In the example below you can see that e.g. value pairs 8-9, 12-13 and 20-21 are missing.

```
value   user    date        value2
1       A      2010-03-02   2
2       A      2010-03-02   3
3       A      2010-03-02   4
4       A      2010-03-02   5
5       A      2010-03-02   6
6       A      2010-03-02   7
7       A      2010-03-02   8
9       B      2010-03-02   10
10      B      2010-03-02   11
11      B      2010-03-02   12
13      C      2010-03-02   14
14      C      2010-03-02   15
15      C      2010-03-02   16
16      C      2010-03-02   17
17      C      2010-03-02   18
18      C      2010-03-02   19
19      C      2010-03-02   20
21      A      2010-03-02   22
22      A      2010-03-02   23
```

With the code below I am almost able to get to the desired result, except for the fact that it also generates the following row:

```
df['value2'] = df.groupby(['user', 'date'])['value'].shift(-1, fill_value=-1)
df = df[df['value2'].ne(-1)]
df

value    user   date         value2
8       A      2010-03-02   21
```

Also, when running this code on a larger dataset, it returns a `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. Any ideas how to fix both issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below , note that your output has `A` repeated later hoeever your input(code) doesnot, hence it might create confusion.

```
out = (df.assign(next_node=
      df.groupby([df['user'].ne(df['user'].shift()).cumsum(),'date'])['node'].shift(-1))
     .dropna(subset=['next_node']))
```

---

```
print(out.reset_index(drop=True))

    node user        date  next_node
0      1    A  2010-03-02        2.0
1      2    A  2010-03-02        3.0
2      3    A  2010-03-02        4.0
3      4    A  2010-03-02        5.0
4      5    A  2010-03-02        6.0
5      6    A  2010-03-02        7.0
6      7    A  2010-03-02        8.0
7      9    B  2010-03-02       10.0
8     10    B  2010-03-02       11.0
9     11    B  2010-03-02       12.0
10    13    C  2010-03-02       14.0
11    14    C  2010-03-02       15.0
12    15    C  2010-03-02       16.0
13    16    C  2010-03-02       17.0
14    17    C  2010-03-02       18.0
15    18    C  2010-03-02       19.0
16    19    C  2010-03-02       20.0
17    21    A  2010-03-02       22.0
18    22    A  2010-03-02       23.0
```

Comment: You're right, I updated my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should be the easiest way:

```
df['next_node'] = df['node'] + 1
df = df.loc[df['user'] == df['user'].shift(-1)]
```

However, if the `df['node']` values are not consecutive integers as in the example then you would have to do it this way:

```
df['next_node'] = df['node'].shift(-1)
df = df.loc[df['user'] == df['user'].shift(-1)]
df = df.astype({'next_node': int})
```

The reason for the extra step is that the shift method converts the type of the series from int to float because it has to add a `np.nan` at the end which is a float value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't return the right output

Comment: Sorry, I fixed a few things.  Try now.

Comment: Although it works, it adds 1 to the `next_node` column, while in fact the values in the dataframe represent non-incremental numbers (this is just a fictional dataset). I'll update my question, to prevent misunderstandings. Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: Note: this method is quite a bit faster than using `groupby`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mental model is misleading you. Instead of thinking of this as "shifting" rows, think of it as calculating a value based on the values in the row below.